# Is it 100% safe to add NOINDEX tag to any duplicate/copy content issues?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, canonical-url, noindex, syndication

> Usually I can simply copy and paste content from any blogs to the
>   my blog, and add a no index tag to avoid any duplicate/copy
>   content issues.

I have copied above part from popular blog. I need to confirm that it is true?

---

My site has two parts.

1. Article Syndication Part
2. Blog Part

I usually **write 4 x 1000+ word articles per month** and **add 100+ syndication posts** from different popular sites.

I am targeting SEO traffic for only my blog?

So is it 100% Safe to add `noindex` tag to all syndication posts to avoid any duplicate/copy content issues?

Or should I have to add `rel=canonical` instead?

So, which is the best one in my case: `noindex` tag or `rel=canonical`?

Answer (score 3):

Both rel=canonical and noindex has their own purposes.

**rel=canonical** should be used when you want to give weightage of the page to a page from where the content originated. The seo juice in this case would be passed to the actual content owner.
So in case you are copying content from other sources, it is a good practice to give them weightage via canonical tag

**rel=noindex** should be used on pages which you don't want crawler to index like logged in user profiles or search result pages etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have not copied all the content. I have just copied only first 100 words and I have added a read more link to original article. For that situation also, is it good to use "rel=canonical"?

Comment: To be clear, `rel=noindex` doesn't prevent the page being _crawled_, it prevents the page being _indexed_.

Answer (score 2):

**No, it is not 100% safe, if you don't own the content, or did not have permission from the original content writer.**

People like me never allowed to republish my content to any website, the link I will get as a reference of original content is generally really poor and will not add tiny value to my website (Also that kind of backlinks heart to any website). So most of SEO experience will not allowed it.

Generally that content I can't find it on Google search, because you have added noindex tag, but that content may be google index it from archive/tags/categories pages if you're using some kind of CMS. If you non-index all the thing, then may be original content will find you from Google search console (Webmaster can see who links to their website) but if you don't link to them also noindex all the copies webpages then it is completely against copyright law.

Most of people will fill [DMCA request against your website](https://support.google.com/legal/answer/1120734) and that webpages will be removed from search result and added it on [lumen database](https://www.lumendatabase.org/). Too much DMCA request will surely heart your SEO.

I don't know what you gonna accomplished, but your technique is consider as blackhat.

**Important note :** Webpages with Noindex tag are crawlable, so Google might already know that your webpages are copied, and will consider your website is low quality.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have not copied all the content. I have just copied only first 100 words and I have added a read more link to original article. Ex : bizsugar.com site is used that technique. Is it also not safe?

Comment: The site you have mention is somehow, aggregated related website. Which is completely fine.

Comment: Thanks again. I am also creating very similar site. Only different is I have added a unique blog too it. My target is getting SEO traffic for unique  blog posts. My problem is **aggregated posts should be noindex tag or canonical **?

Comment: What's the purpose of that webpages, if you're going to use noindex or canonical link tag. Those webpages will never get any traffic from SERP, so what's the purpose of those? Just to add as much content in your website? or revenue from ads?.

Comment: Thnaks for asking it. It is for just user experience. That site is all about WordPress. I write 1000+ article per week. And I added many aggregated posts about WordPress. Users can vote those articles also. Final result is my site has thousands of WordPress related resources. (Because of aggregated posts, my blog posts should not be affected SEO perspective, that's why I asked what tag is used for aggregated posts  ).