# If website 410 / removes a page and I have a copy can I use that content on my website

Tags: seo, google, duplicate-content

ok so 2 issues here, I believe the title pretty much describes what I am asking / trying to do. A website has a page which they have decided to remove, I have a cached copy, may I use that content on my site, and put a link back NOT to the removed page but to the root domain.

The 3 questions here are:

1) **Is this considered unethical (main concern)**, remember I am providing a link back to the homepage?

2) Will this be seen as duplicate content even though the page is removed?

3) Is there anything else I should know?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this considered unethical (main concern), remember I am providing a
>   link back to the homepage?

If you don't have permission to publish it, then you should not do that. The link is likely do not add any value, and it may harmful as well, if site is new.

> Will this be seen as duplicate content even though the page is
>   removed?

Probably, yes, since Google already have the cache version of that website.

> Is there anything else I should know?

[Yes, read this answer.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100040/is-it-100-safe-to-add-noindex-tag-to-any-duplicate-copy-content-issues/100062#100062)

Comment: Keep in mind that in most countries this would be illegal due to copyright and can result in a DCMA complaint at the least and a law suit at the most. In the U.S., most copyright law suits are Federal and would cost at least $10,000 in legal fees just to attain a legal settlement. Then comes the settlement fee and any fine levied thereafter. Keep in mind, that in some cases, even a settlement can result in government action such as arrest , fines, and possibly jail as a result of the prima facie nature of most settlements. Not a good situation even when it all goes as well as it can.